# Most effective way of sorting arrya

Tags: algorithm, sorting, theory, any

What is the most effective way of sorting array in any language ?
With lowest O() and P(). I find that shell sorting is one of the best way how to sort but is there something quicker?

Comment: Quicksort is probably the fastest general-purpose algorithm, with a speed of O(n logn)

Comment: What's the most effective way to find out the answer to this question? Google...

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/18545

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it short:

Introsort and Timsort are the most commonly used sorting algorithms in real world.

They have both an O(nlogn) complexity in average and on worst cases which makes them better than QuickSort in the particular cases where Quicksort is in O(n^2). Introsort is used in C and C++ STL and Timsort is used in Python and Java implementations (at least for sorting arrays of Objects in Java).

Shell sort is in O(n(logn)^2) so slightly slower but uses less memory so can be suitable for embedded systems. See [enter link description here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) for more details

Comment: Heap sort uses O(1) memory and O(nlogn) time, wouldn't it be better than shell sort?

Comment: yes it has also a small memory usage but comparing sorting algorithms in embedded systems is a delicate subject. See : http://embeddedgurus.com/stack-overflow/2009/03/sorting-in-embedded-systems/ for example